# Positioning a header bar next to a sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using bootstrap and  want to add a header bar to the right of the sidebar, so it aligns next to it, without sitting on top. The sidebar is also collapsible, so the header would have to extend to the whole page once the sidebar is collapsed.

[image: like this]

Sidebar code:

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Have you attempted to create some CSS markup for this?

Comment: Tried using the default bootstrap navbar within and outside of the wrapper, but it stacks above or pushes the sidebar down with the height of the bootstrap navbar

Comment: Create some CSS and give it a try... You may want to keep the CSS property margin-left in mind.

Comment: Bootstrap is a column based layout too. if something is a 2 column sidebar - the main area can only be 10 columns wide.

Comment: nevermind did it with the default navbar by positioning it within the wrapper, but below the side-bar nav div, realize it's petty for someone to just do your work for you, sorry for the nature of the question, it's all done and good now

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're already using bootstrap, why don't you add the already built column classes to your markup. Be sure you have Bootstrap CSS included.

`<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="col-lg-3">`

Then on your Header...

`<div id="header-wrapper" class="col-lg-9">`

Also just did a pen [found here](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/amdQmg)

It would be a good idea to take advantage of the column classes as it make responsive design easier.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with the default navbar by positioning it within the wrapper, but below the side-bar nav div, no extra positioning needed.